# Unexpected display for multiple way of opening/closing a popup

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events

I was trying to open/close a popup with a variable,
it shows when the input field is focused, vice versa.
But there would be an icon that allowing user to click on it,
the icon can toggle the display of the popup.

Here is the code snippet:

```js
// Get references to the input field and the popup
const inputField = document.getElementById("inputField");
const popup = document.getElementById("popup");
const toggleIcon = document.getElementById("toggleIcon");

// Variable to track the visibility state of the popup
let isPopupVisible = false;

// Function to show the popup
function showPopup() {
  console.log("showing");
  popup.style.display = "block";
  isPopupVisible = true;
}

// Function to hide the popup
function hidePopup() {
  console.log("hiding");
  popup.style.display = "none";
  isPopupVisible = false;
}

// Function to toggle the visibility of the popup
function togglePopup() {
  console.log("toggle", isPopupVisible ? "true" : "false");
  if (isPopupVisible) {
    hidePopup();
  } else {
    showPopup();
  }
}

// Event handler for when the input field is focused
inputField.addEventListener("focus", function () {
  if (!isPopupVisible) {
    showPopup();
  }
});

// Event handler for when the input field is blurred
inputField.addEventListener("blur", function () {
  hidePopup();
});

// Event handler for when the toggle icon is clicked
toggleIcon.addEventListener("click", function () {
  togglePopup();
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Popup Example</title>
  <style>
    .popup {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #f9f9f9;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      padding: 10px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="inputField" placeholder="Enter text">
  <span id="toggleIcon">&#x1F441;</span>
  <div id="popup" class="popup">
    This is the popup content.
  </div>

  <script>
    // JavaScript code goes here
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

But with specific procedures, an unexpected showing popup spotted:

```
1. click the icon to show the popup
2. click the input field to focus on it, the popup still showing
3. click the icon
Expected: the popup should be hidden
Result: the popup hides and shows back
```

And with the console log, I found that the onblur event of the input is triggered before it calls the icon toggle function.

```
"toggle: isPopupVisible=false"
"showing"
"hiding"
"toggle: isPopupVisible=false"
"showing"
```

so for this case, how can i update my code to have the effect?

I cannot just hide the popup with something `display: none;`, because for my real case,
i need the isPopupVisible to do the other thing apart from displaying a popup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of your issue is because the because two events fire when you click the icon with the popup visible from the `focus` of the input. First the `blur` of the input hides the popup, then the click of the icon toggles the popup and displays it again.

To fix the issue you can listen for a click *outside* the `input`, not it's `blur` event, with exceptions for the clicks on the `input` and `icon`.

Also note that your variable to store the visible state of the popup is redundant and causes unnecessary complexity. The DOM already holds the state, so use that as the single source of truth. In fact, you can simplify the showing/hiding/toggling by using a class with `display: block` on it and updating that class as necessary.

With that said, here's a working version with the above changes made:

```js
const inputField = document.getElementById("inputField");
const popup = document.getElementById("popup");
const toggleIcon = document.getElementById("toggleIcon");

const showPopup = () => popup.classList.add('show');
const hidePopup = () => popup.classList.remove('show');
const togglePopup = () => popup.classList.toggle('show');

// Event handler for when the input field is focused
inputField.addEventListener("focus", function() {
  showPopup();
});

// Event handler for when a click occurs outside of an element which affects the popup
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target != inputField && e.target != toggleIcon) {
    hidePopup();
  }
});

// Event handler for when the toggle icon is clicked
toggleIcon.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  togglePopup();
});
```

```css
.popup {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
}

.popup.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inputField" placeholder="Enter text">
<span id="toggleIcon">&#x1F441;</span>
<div id="popup" class="popup">
  This is the popup content.
</div>
```

Comment: I will still keeping the variable because i need it to do another stuff, but yea adding event listener is what i need for this case, thank you so much!